# SwiftUI Widget Previews have a padding in iOS 17 / Xcode 15

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, widgetkit, ios17

After iOS 17 / Xcode 15 the previews for my widgets are inset and squeezed into the view.

[image: SwiftUI preview issue]

I added a *.contentMarginsDisabled()* modifier to the intent, which fixes this in the actual widgets on a device, but the previews still show it with the padding.

```
struct SmallWidgetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ForEach(BasketballWidgetEntry.mockEntries) { entry in
      GeometryReader { geometry in
        SmallWidgetView(
          entry: entry,
          width: geometry.size.width,
          height: geometry.size.height,
          colorSet: .colorSetOrange
        )
      }
      .previewContext(
        WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

```
@main
struct BasketballWidgetAppWidget: Widget {
  let kind: String = "BasketballWidgetAppWidget"

  var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    IntentConfiguration(
      kind: kind,
      intent: ConfigurationIntent.self,
      provider: Provider()
    ) { entry in
      WidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
    }
    .configurationDisplayName("Basketball Team Scores")
    .description("You favorite team's basketball team scores")
    .supportedFamilies([
      .systemSmall,
      .systemMedium,
      .systemLarge,
      .accessoryCircular
    ])
    .contentMarginsDisabled()
  }
}
```

What am I possibly missing here? :)

// Update
As requested here is also the implementation of SmallWidgetView

```
struct SmallWidgetView: View {
  let entry: BasketballWidgetEntry
  let width: CGFloat
  let height: CGFloat
  let colorSet: WidgetColorSet

  var body: some View {
    let index = entry.favoriteIndex

    VStack(spacing: 0) {
      StandingsListSmall(
        entry: entry,
        favoriteIndex: index,
        width: width,
        colorSet: colorSet
      )
      .padding(.bottom, 0)
    }
    .font(.caption)
    .frame(width: width, height: height, alignment: .center)
    .backgroundColor(colorSet.backgroundMain)
    .overlay(
      NextGameSmallWidgetView(
        width: width,
        match: MatchFunctions.getNextMatch(matches: entry.matches),
        favoriteId: entry.favoriteId,
        colorSet: colorSet
      ),
      alignment: .bottom
    )
    .overlay(
      FavoriteTeamHeader(
        entry: entry,
        index: index,
        width: width,
        colorSet: colorSet
      ),
      alignment: .topLeading
    )
    .widgetBackground(Color.black)
  }
}
```

Comment: There are a few views you haven't shown implementations for here. e.g. `SmallWidgetView`?

Comment: Good point @shim, I added the smallWidgetView :) . I also saw the line .frame(width: width, height: height, alignment: .center) - making these values manually larger does allow the view to go outside the inset. Is maybe the GeometryReader in the preview not working as intended, and not getting the correct height and width values?

Comment: In my experience `GeometryReader` is pretty annoying to work with as it causes problems like this. Generally views should be written in such a way that they can dynamically scale without knowing the explicit dimensions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround! Apparently at the moment the GeometryReader, when used in WidgetPreviews, is not getting the full size of the widget.

Adding a negative padding of 16 fixes this for the previews.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
  SmallWidgetView(
    entry: entry,
    width: geometry.size.width,
    height: geometry.size.height,
    colorSet: .colorSetOrange
  )
}
.padding(-16)
.previewContext(
  WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall)
)
```